# Div not aligned in the center in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm working on a website and all looks fine in Firefox, Chrome etc. except for IE. I am using Ryan Fait's Sticky footer method and I have the following styles on my main div:

```
#bigcontent{
    width: 920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    /* etc etc */
}
```

Code for the footer:

```
.footer{
    background-color: #585858;
    color: #fafafa;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 220px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 4px -2px #333;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 4px -2px #333;
    box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px -2px #333;
}
```

I use `<!DOCTYPE html>` (html5 doctype)
I really don't know what the problem is.

The strangest thing is. My homepage is centered well. i don't use the #bigcontent on that page so it  should be a problem with that specific div.

Screenshots of how it looks:

-- Removed images --

Comment: You should add some markup to the question, help us reproduce this issue.

Comment: what do you need? ask what you need and i will provide code.

Comment: Ideally a link to a jsFiddle reproducing the issue, if possible.

Comment: will try to fix that.

Comment: Hm. it is working in the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q5dpr/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried forcing IE into standards mode?  Add this to the `<head>` of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are seeing the website with IE in **Compatibility Mode**. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> and check `Browser Mode`.

Comment: My browsermode is Internet Explorer 9. so that isn't the problem.

Comment: @KeesSonnema What about `Document Mode`. Is it set to `Standards`?